# Управление профилями и компьютерами в Samba4

Tags: samba, linux

Правильно ли я понимаю, что [возможности управление профилями и компьютерами в Samba4](http://www.golinuxhub.com/2012/08/create-roaming-profiles-in-samba4.html) ограничены виндузовыми клиентами? Или все-таки есть возможность организовать перемещаемые профили внутри сети, где все машины - линуксовые?

Answer (score 1):

Samba как раз и создана для общения Linux-to-Windows, или наоборот. Для гомогенной Linux-сети то же можно, но не рационально ибо есть свои решения, более быстрые.
[Посмотрите здесь - очень подробно расписывается](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=123019)
[Контроллер домена под (на) Линукс](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=84474)
[Аналоги AD в Линукс](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=101428)